# How can I extract Azure IP ranges json file programatically through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, wget

I want to download the `ipranges.json` (which is updated weekly) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519
I have this python code which keeps running forever.

```
import wget
URL = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519"
response = wget.download(URL, "ips.json")
print(response)
```

How can I download the JSON file in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519` is the link which automatically trigger javascript to download, therefore you just download the page, not the file

If you check downloaded file, the source will look like this

[image]

We realize the file will change after a while, so we have to scrape it in generic way

For convenience, I will not use wget, 2 libraries here are `requests` to request page and download file, `beaufitulsoup` to parse html

```
# pip install requests
# pip install bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# request page
URL = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519"
page = requests.get(URL)

# parse HTML to get the real link
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
link = soup.find('a', {'data-bi-containername':'download retry'})['href']

# download
file_download = requests.get(link)

# save in azure_ips.json
open("azure_ips.json", "wb").write(file_download.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Great solution, I added custom headers because I was getting back an error from the URL saying that I was using an automation user-agent string. Here is how it looks now:

```py
# request page with modified headers
URL = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
logging.info(page.content)
```